# Change backgroundImage with javascript for image slideshow.

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the background image of a div depending on it's id and then make a slideshow with a couple of images. I'm able to change the background with javascript but have a hard time figuring out why my loop doesn't work.

main.js

```
var spotlight = document.getElementById('spotlight');
var pics = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
var totalPics = pics.length;
var i = 0;
function loop() {
    if(i > (totalPics - 1)) {
        i = 0;
    }
    spotlight.style.backgroundImage="url(/images/posts/'+pics[i]+')";
    i++;
    loopTimer = setTimeout('loop()',1000);
}
loop();
```

I'm using sass, but as javascript is client side this shouldn't work any different I guess? What am I doing wrong in my loop?
I have followed the basic principles found on w3Schools of changing the style with javascript and it works with a static image so my guess is that I have done something wrong in the loop.

Thanks

Comment: You made a mistake here : `spotlight.style.backgroundImage="url(/images/posts/'+pics[i]+')";` 
TIP : look for the quotes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
spotlight.style.backgroundImage="url(/images/posts/" + pics[i]+ ")";
```

and

```
loopTimer = setTimeout(loop,1000);
```

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your setTimeout to the following

```
loopTimer = setTimeout('loop', 1000);
```